# How to add a progress bar(loading circle) while the API returns the results?

Tags: c#, android, asynchronous, xamarin.android, progress-bar

I'm a newbie to Xamarin Android and C#, I want to add a progress bar(loading circle) while the API returns the results.

This is my Progress Bar,

```
ProgressBar mProgressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBarConfirmJob);

 mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
```

I have the following API on button click event,

```
btnSubmit.Click += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            var jobId = txtJobID.Text;

            if (txtJobID.Text.Length <= 0)
            {
                txtJobID.RequestFocus();
                txtJobID.SetError("Job ID required", iconError);
            }
            else
            {
                var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("http://192.168.79.174:90/api/test/" + jobId));
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Method = "GET";

                mProgressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


                using (HttpWebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)
                {

                    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        Console.Out.WriteLine("Error fetching data. Server returned status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

                        dynamic arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content);

                        foreach (dynamic obj in arr)
                        {
                            tvJobID.Text = obj.JobID;
                            tvJobType.Text = obj.JobType;
                            tvDueDate.Text = obj.DueDate;
                            tvVisitTime.Text = obj.Time;
                            tvVisitStatus.Text = obj.VisitStatus;
                            tvAddress1.Text = obj.Address1;
                            tvAddress2.Text = obj.Address2;
                            tvPostCode.Text = obj.PostCode;
                            tvAuthority.Text = obj.Authority;
                        }

                        if (content == null || content == "" || content == "[]")
                        {

                            //Console.Out.WriteLine("Response contained empty body...");
                            layoutController.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                            Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "Invalid Job ID or no visits for this ID. Please try again", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            layoutController.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        };
```

I have this in the .axml

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="51.0dp"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px">
            <ProgressBar xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/progressBarRaiseJob"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

How can I display the progress bar until the the Web API returns results. At the moment, Progress bar appears for 2 seconds and then it freeze until the API returns results, I'm assuming the issue is with the Asynchronous process? Any idea where I'm going wrong, Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: Try using events or async/await so you don't block the UI Thread.

Comment: I added the Aync and await, but where shall I use the ProgressBar?

Answer (score 0):

In async task, in pre execute method display the progress bar and in post execute method remove the progress bar. use visibility options gone for removing the bar.